# Targeting a specific hyperlink and turning it into a button

Tags: css, button, hyperlink

So i have a page and want to change a hyperlink into a button using css.

I found out that by using:

a {background-color: green} this changes the background colour of all the hyperlinks on the page, and across the site, to green, which makes them all look like buttons. I just want to target one specific hyperlink and also want to change the text colour.

a {color: green;} does nothing to change the text color.

So, how do i target a specific hyperlink and change text colour and background colour to make it look like a button?

I found div above it and it was awpcp-subtitle. So i tried awpcp-subtitle a { background-color: green;} nothing happened.

There is one hyperlink with html source: "Old Goriot", link - http://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/10/old-goriot/london/uk/books/

```
link rel="amphtml" href="http://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test- 
dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/amp/" /><link rel='dns- 
prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" 
title="Adsler &raquo; Feed" 
href="http://adsler.co.uk/feed/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" 
title="Adsler &raquo; Comments Feed" 
href="http://adsler.co.uk/comments/feed
```

How do I change this colour and background colour?

In addition, i want to turn the telephone label and number into button which just says" sms".

Also on this page, i want the picture to expand fit in the box. At the moment it's totally skewed to the right in mobile view and off centre desktop.

Also want another box to surround phone , email etc.

The solutions below are very good, but was wondering if there is a site wide solution for all the hyperlinks in that class. As it is, I have to change each one individually and it doesn't modify my theme to create this as an inherent styling configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for that. Take a look at the following:

```css
a[href="google.com"] {
  background: red;
  color: black;
}

a[href="youtube.com"] {
  background: blue;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
<a href="youtube.com">YouTube</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. So your code to target specific hyperlink background worked. But the code to target the text color didn't.

Comment: @Adsler what do you mean with "to target the text color didn't"? Is there already styling which overwrites the color? Without any CSS it is hard to tell

Comment: Hi. There's styling which overwrites ( .btn), but nothing to override the 'a' selector.

Comment: if you apply `.btn` to `a` than it is still overwriting. One way to force hyperlink to overwrite is to apply `!important` to the end of property you want to force but it is quite bad. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Hi. That did work, adding 'important', but overwrote all color styling including the element i wanted to specify. I just want to target that one hyperlink text color. Possible? Thanks.

Comment: @Adsler if you supply more CSS I can give you a more suitable answer but I can't right now

Comment: @Adsler Btw, do you know how to change the text itself? From 'contact' to 'email'? that is something to ask for in a new question